# SNMP: Would linkDown trap be notified after link status becomes up?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

The linkDown trap description states: 
"A linkDown trap signifies that the SNMPv2 entity, acting in an agent role, has detected that the ifOperStatus object for one of its communication **links left the down state and transitioned into some other state (but not into the notPresent state).** 
This other state is indicated by the included value of ifOperStatus."

Does it mean LINKDOWN alert would be notified after they go up ? Not at the moment that they go into down status ?

Answer (score 2):

That wording doesn't match the wording in the most recent version of the IF-MIB, which is the best source:

```
DESCRIPTION   "A linkDown trap signifies that the SNMP entity, acting in
        an agent role, has detected that the ifOperStatus object for
        one of its communication links is about to enter the down
        state from some other state (but not from the notPresent
        state).  This other state is indicated by the included value
        of ifOperStatus."
```

Note that in the above it says the agent should send it when the link is about to go down.

However, I think you'll find most agent's don't necessarily support it that way very well.  And the notification may only get sent after it goes down.  It's nice in theory to think the above is the way it can be done, but picture a link going down because someone pulls the cable.  It doesn't matter if the kernel is about to set it as "down".  It still can't deliver a message over it, and functionally it's already down.

However, if the receiving management station is connected via another link, it'll still get the notification.